# AS3 Integration With Azure Cloud Hosting

Tags: azure, ftp, aptana

Does anyone know if [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) can integrate directly with Azure cloud hosting like it does with Heroku or Engine Yard? Want to avoid the GitHub option if possible as public account.

Comment: @astaykov That was a typo, I meant AS3. Thx.

Comment: OK, and what is AS3 ?! Action Script 3? Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and be as descriptive as possible in your questions.

Comment: It's Aptana Studio 3 - an IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official site for Aptana Studio 3 I see that it supports FTP as a standard publishing method.

You can use this method (ftp) to Deploy your application to [Windows Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/). And [here is a quick tutorial on how to publish to Azure Web Sites using FTP](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/tutorials/website-w-mysql-and-ftp/). It will guide you through the process of creating deployment credentials and how to get the FTP site address.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at other IDE solutions and recently came across PHPStorm - it has ftp, SVN and Azure integration as standard (amongst others) so am going to stick with it and because it's also an excellent code editor. Happy days!